# How do a build a lens for passing to purescript's `Thermite.focus`?

Tags: purescript

I am following various Thermite tutorials about setting up task lists. The only tutorial with a lot of explanation is also quite far out of date, so I am modifying it to fit the current Thermite. However, I have one call in which I cannot make the data types match.

```
import Optic.Lens (lens)
import Optic.Prism (prism)
import Optic.Types (Prism', Lens')
import Thermite as T

_TaskAction :: Prism' TaskListAction (Tuple Int TaskAction)
_TaskAction = ...

_tasks :: Lens' TaskListState (L.List TaskState)
_tasks = lens _.tasks (_ { tasks = _ })

taskList :: T.Spec _ TaskListState _ TaskListAction
taskList = T.focus _tasks _TaskAction taskSpec
```

However, this gives me an error message:

```
  Could not match type

    p0

  with type

    Function

while trying to match type p0 t1
  with type Function             
              (List              
                 { text :: String
                 }               
              )                  
while checking that expression _tasks
  has type p0 t1 t1 -> p0 t2 t2
in value declaration taskList

where p0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at line 213, column 20 - line 213, column 26
      t1 is an unknown type
      t2 is an unknown type
```

The error message is specifically talking about the `_tasks` parameter I am passing to `T.focus`. But I do not know what the error is trying to tell me. I also know that the type signature for `T.focus` is...

```
focus :: forall eff props state2 state1 action1 action2.
         Lens' state2 state1
      -> Prism' action2 action1
      -> Spec eff state1 props action1
      -> Spec eff state2 props action2
```

So, the first parameter is a lens.

More frustratingly, I've checked more modern (but larger and less comprehensible) example code, and it shows exactly the same definition for `_tasks` as I have here.

So, what does this error message mean, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: You're using the wrong lens library. Thermite uses `profunctor-lenses`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. If you promote it to an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're importing `Optic.Lens` suggests that you're using the wrong lens library here. `purescript-lens` provides traditional van-Laarhoven lenses (like Haskell's `lens` library), but Thermite uses the `profunctor-lenses` library.